# Querying SQL for multiple records

Tags: sql, select

I have a table containing some information, and my wish is to make a select query to retrieve the wanted informations.

My table looks like,

```
Column1     Column2     column3     ...
Company1    Doc1
Company1    Doc2
Company1    Doc3
Company2    Doc1
Company2    Doc3
Company3    Doc1
...
```

So what I want is, to select all the companies containing all three documents. That is, if Compan1 contains Doc1, Doc2, Doc3, select it. If it only contains Doc2 and Doc3, or anything else, do not select it.

So overall, I want a overview of all the companies containing those exact three documents.

Hope it gives sense :).

Comment: For wich RDBMS?
You said your table contains: Company1 Doc1 Company1 Doc2 Company1 Doc3 Company2 Doc1 Company2 Doc3 Company3 Doc1 .. So it has only two columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select column1
from the_table
where column2 in ('Doc1', 'Doc2', 'Doc3')
group by column1
having count(distinct column2) = 3;
```

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name (lol). I needed the the "where in" clause, and the "having count". Thanks.